# Iota explorer installation fails for private tangle

Tags: docker

I'am trying to start the explorer for a private tangle by following the steps in https://github.com/iotaledger/one-click-tangle.

The explorer installation process (running the command: ./tangle-explorer.sh install ../hornet-private-net) end with the following error:

```
Cloning into './explorer-src'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 30881, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (5015/5015), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (1127/1127), done.
remote: Total 30881 (delta 3971), reused 4816 (delta 3808), pack-reused 25866
Receiving objects: 100% (30881/30881), 16.57 MiB | 2.44 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (25255/25255), done.
Updating files: 100% (980/980), done.
Stopping containers...
Warning: No resource found to remove for project "explorer".
Config
0d8387f5adda55c7bad53082fedc88c12763f4e8fc6d9ebf1ce48e0751b0d46d
cp: cannot create regular file './explorer-src/client/src/assets/config/config.local.json': No such file or directory
```

It looks like the config directory does not exsist.

If I try to start the explorer (./tangle-explorer.sh start) the explorer-webapp and explorer-api containers are created, but at http://localhost:8082 I get a blank page. Also, the explorer-api container stops continuously.

I've tryed to create the config.local.json manually, but I still get an empty page.

These are my config files:

**webapp.config.local.json**

```
{
  "apiEndpoint": "http://localhost:4000",
  "googleAnalyticsId": "GOOGLE-ANALYTICS-ID",
  "identityResolverEnabled": true
}
```

**private-network.json**

```
{
  "network": "tangle",
  "label": "Tangle",
  "provider": "http://node1:14265",
  "protocolVersion": "chrysalis",
  "feedEndpoint": "mqtt://node1:1883",
  "coordinatorAddress": "",
  "primaryColor": "#131F37",
  "secondaryColor": "#485776",
  "isEnabled": true,
  "showMarket": false,
  "order": 0,
  "description": "Private Tangle Network"
}
```

**api.config.local.file**

```
{
  "fixerApiKey": "FIXER-API-KEY",
  "rootStorageFolder": "/app/data/.local-storage",
  "allowedDomains": [
      "*"
  ],
  "verboseLogging": true
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like that one-click-tangle repo isn't updated for the latest "stardust" version of the Explorer.

The team will fix it, but in the meantime you can try the following (if you can ssh in the running container of the client side AND if i'm correct that you cloned latest main branch):
Do the first step explained here under "Configuration"
https://github.com/iotaledger/explorer/blob/dev/client/DEPLOYMENT.md

Basically the way that we configure the API_ENDPOINT on the client side has changed meanwhile. I think that's why you are getting a blank page.

*Credit goes to Mario on Discord*